# restart activity from from scratch after system killed the app process

Tags: android

When activity is restored after was being killed by the system (I mean app process was killed, and process restarts with old activities stack), activity restore old it's state -
is it possible to clear this activity state and restart activity from from scratch.

Comment: You could just opt out of actually reading the saved state.

Comment: how? please add more details.

Comment: android:alwaysRetainTaskState="false" ?

Comment: um just don't do anything. Like if it got killed, the onCreate() will be called again. Just don't read any state, just go and redo it all

Comment: I don't read any state, but after killing the activity starts not from scratch(it remember it's old layout). :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check which method is called when your activity is killed...onDestroy() or onPause(), as most probably. When "killed" your activity is not actually destroyed, it is paused, hence onResume() is executed, as your state is preserved. To destroy the activity you can use finish() in your onPause() method, have a look at **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131585/how-to-destroy-an-activity-in-android)** on how to do it.